# Mass Effect 3 Loading Glitch

Tags: mass-effect-3, technical-issues

I'm on the first priority mission of the game, and when I get to the part with the turret, a few waves pass- and then nothing happens. Ever.
I just get an infinite loading circle at the bottom right, and some of the characters phase in and out of existance, and teleport sometimes.

Just what the heck is going on?
And how do I fix this?

Comment: Mission: Priority: Palaven

Comment: What platform is this on? Do you have it on a disc, or download?

Comment: Disk, PS3. I've already fixed this problem, for some reason it was because I wasn't using the turret.                                                                                                                         Edit:I still want to know the reason though.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I remember running into the same issue myself when I didn't use the turret (on 360). Obviously a bug of some sort, rather than a machine/disc issue. Glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 1):

Use the turret instead of fighting off the enemies with your guns.
The resulting glitch is from not using the turret... For some reason.

Have fun with the rest of the game, me!